# XHR State Error when readyState is as expected

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a JavaScript program which requires significant usage of XHR methods. I am using the asynchronous style. This is the core of what I have.

```
        global = {};
        global.xhr = {};
        global.xhr.requestQueue = [];
        global.xhr.responseQueue = [];

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.first = true;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //console.log(this.readyState);
            if(this.readyState == 4) {
                if(this.first) {
                    this.first = false;
                    global.carouselItems = parseInt(this.responseText);
                    global.onSlideCountReceived();
                } else {
                    global.xhr.responseQueue.push({status: xhr.status, responseText: xhr.responseText});
                    if(global.xhr.requestQueue.length > 0) {
                        xhr.open("GET", global.xhr.requestQueue[0]);
                        global.xhr.requestQueue.shift();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(xhr.readyState == 1) {
                xhr.send();
            }
        }
        //Code which adds a bunch of items to global.xhr.requestQueue
        xhr.open("GET","assets/carousel/items.php");
```

But when I run this, the Chrome Dev console prints a bunch of errors like the following.

`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

This is despite the only call to `xhr.send()` being in the snippet above, wrapped in its `if` statement. This is confusing to me, because the way I see it suggests that I make a call to `xhr.send()` when `xhr.readyState` is `1`, equivalent to `XMLHttpRequest.OPENED` and yet I get a complaint about this not being the case.

By the way,  the requests all complete successfully, and `global.xhr.responseQueue` is populated with expected response info. These are  all intra-domain requests.

Comment: Do you use Node.js? If so, you have to add appropriate tag.

Comment: Good question. No. This is included in an HTTP response from a .html file to a user's browser. I left out the `node.js` tag because this is the case.

Comment: Is `xhr` intentionally a global variable? That looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes, `xhr` is intended to be global. Why is that a bad idea? None of the APIs I am using here uses a global variable with that name.